# RESTful json response failing on tomcat but works in GlassFish

Tags: json, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, spring-mvc

Here is the method I have which responds back with JSON response. This code works on GlassFish but I'm getting an error when I run on tomcat 7.0.27

HTTP Status: 406

The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", headers="Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, ? extends Object> getAuthPOST(@RequestBody String jsonBody) throws JSONException {                        
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(jsonBody);
    System.out.println(j.keys());
    Iterator i = j.keys();
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    while (i.hasNext()) {            
        String key = (String) i.next();
        result.put(String.valueOf(key), String.valueOf(j.getString(key)));
    }        
    return result;

}
```

UPDATE:

Here are the headers when I get the request back

HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Content-Length: 1070
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 02 May 2012 15:47:24 GMT
Connection: close

It changes the Content-Type to text/html.

Here are my request headers:

POST /SpringMVC/login/test HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which version of spring-mvc you are using, but if you are on 3.1 you can add the "produces" parameter to your @RequestMapping.  `produces="application/json"`

Comment: Yes I'm on 3.1. produces didn't work. I'm still getting the same error as response.

Comment: I fixed it by including jackson-jaxrs library.